# Easing on Fixed Position Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there anyway to add a easing to a fixed element?, I've been looking around and I can't find an answer. I really don't know how it would be, maybe something like...

```
$(window).scroll(function() { 
    $("#form").animate({position:"fixed", easing: 'swing'});
});
```

Any help will be appreciated ^ ^ Thanks!

Edit:Pretty much what I'm looking for is when user scrolls, the fixed element obviously will follow the window position, but I want to add is a little delay in comparison to scroll action with an easing effect

Comment: what kind of movement { position: fixed } is going to produce? seems like a paradox to me

Comment: ya sorry a bit of lack of explanation edited my question

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to make that div absolute positioned, z-indexed and without parent, then move it on the scroll event. You can know the number of pixels scrolled with scrollTop(). Something like this:

```
  $(window).scroll(function(){ 
     var offset=100;
     //stop is called so easing doesn't affect while it is still scrolling.
     $("form").stop().animate({top:($(window).scrollTop()+offset)+"px"}, 300, 'swing');

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$("#form").animate({position:"fixed"}, 300, 'swing');
```

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery api ( http://api.jquery.com/animate/ ):

> The only easing implementations in the jQuery library are the default,
>   called swing, and one that progresses at a constant pace, called
>   linear. More easing functions are available with the use of plug-ins,
>   most notably the [jQuery UI suite](http://jqueryui.com/).

```
$("form").animate({position:"fixed"}, 300, 'swing'); //swing being default
```